# Getting my FanPage wall feed without Application using .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to show the latest updates from my fan page wall on my blog using .NET (C#/VB).

After reading [Facebook Graph API Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) I understand that I need access_token to make this call - The problem is that I don't want to ask every visitor to approve any kind of Facebook App just to read the updates feed.

I think it's possible because I noticed that [Wibiya's Toolbar](http://www.wibiya.com/) show's wall feed without asking permissions but somehow, they got access_token to make this call.

Can someone help me to crack this mystery or just telling me what is the best way to achieve this?

Please don't offer me the ordinary Facebook widget.

Comment: keyword: "application token" check the authentication page on facebook docs

Comment: AFAIK you just need the access token for the fan page. You don't need each user to approve anything.

Comment: access token is needed for JSON requests outside the fan page.

Comment: Why is it that people don't bother providing Answers, but they do bother commenting the question. If you have an answer, provide it as an answer! Then we can vote and elaborate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible answer is to simply use the RSS feed for the fan page - If you look at the bottom left of any "Fan page" you will the following links:

```
* Create a Page
* Add to My Page's Favorites
* Subscribe via RSS
* Report Page
* Share
```

The Facebook fan page RSS feed looks something like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=FACEBOOK-ID&format=rss20
```

So if I wanted to read the Coca Cola Facebook fan page (id: 40796308305), you could simply use:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=40796308305&format=rss20
```

There are no 'Social Plugins' that I know of, that allow you to display your facebook fan page status updates, like the twitter widget does. (afaik)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution,
We can approach it by using [FQL Queries](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

```
SELECT source_id,post_id,actor_id,target_id,message,comments,likes,attachment,created_time,permalink FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()LIMIT 0,15
```

I hope you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you do not need programming if you want to do that if you have the ability to embedded javascript and html in your blog then use  javascript sdk it will help you a lot or use one of the Facebook plugins all you need to d is to give it the URL and here are some useful links :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

mark as answered if it helps :)

Comment: I'm sorry - Your answer didn't help, Please make sure you read the WHOLE question before answering (Please don't offer me the ordinary Facebook widget.)